# Passing a parameter to use a property key. Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

How do you pass a parameter to a function that you can use a property key.

For example

```
myFunctionToSetState = (propertyName) => {

    //I want to use the string I pass as the key in my new object
    this.setState({ propertyName: newValue});
}

//I'm calling the function like this
this.myFunctionToSetState('myPropertKey');
```

It seems that propertyName is never the parameter I passed and is always a key called propertyName.

I want to basically pass a property of my redux state to this function at update accordingly. The value I'm setting is actually an image uri. However I have multiple pictures I want to reference.

Thanks

Comment: Note that this will most certainly break when you minify your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets for dynamic property names:

```
this.setState({ [propertyName]: newValue });
```

See the 'Bracket Notation' section of the [Property accessors docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for more information.

Comment: Man, you are a life saver! Thanks for the reference to the docs aswell